# searching through a string-array in android

Tags: android, listview, search, arrays

I have a rather large string-array with a lot of strings (obviously), and i want to put a search bar in the top.
This string array comes out in a listview. I want to be able to search for some string in the list, and then hide the results that does not match my search, and only show the items that match what i searched for.

I just cant figure out how to setup the code to search through my string-array.

Code for the listview

```
Resources res = getResources();
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    final String[] ids = res.getStringArray(R.array.idchart_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,ids);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My search code:

```
final EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.srcBox);
Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.srcBtn);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
for (String s : ids) {
if (searchField.getText().toString().contains(s)) {
}
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple (not optimized) way:

**Your ListView Code**

---

Use ArrayList instead of Array, because you can not modify the Array after adding it to the ArrayAdapter

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        final String[] ids = res.getStringArray(R.array.idchart_array);
        ArrayList<String> idList = Arrays.asList(ids);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,idList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Your Search Code**

```
List<String> foundStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String s : ids){
            if(s.contains(searchField.getText().toString())){
                foundStrings.add(s);
            }
        }

        idList.clear();
        idList.addAll(foundStrings);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hmm... i tried but it didn't work, i replaced my for loop with your part.

Comment: Also i had to import some libs that weren't android, so im wondering if what you wrote is android compatible

Comment: what i wrote is plain java and works on android. yes, you have to import java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList but your IDE should do this for you

Comment: it did, and there are no errors, but its not implementing it to my listview